# Is it possible to lock SIM card programmatically in android device

Tags: android

In my application I want the functionality which will lock the current SIM card after some condition met.

So is it possible to lock the SIM card programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that due to the Android security policy

Comment: How about locking the SIM card programmatically from a **System app**?